Angular app not retrieving localStorage/sessionStorage on deep links with current production .htaccess configuration
I'm working on an Angular 18 application that uses localStorage and sessionStorage to store user data. Everything works fine when I access the site using the root URL, like https://www.example.com/. However, when I access a deep link directly, such as https://www.example.com/specificSubRoute/anID, the localStorage and sessionStorage appear to be empty.
This issue does not happen when I'm running the application locally; it only occurs in the production environment hosted in a 1&1 ASP.NET server solution.
When accessing deep links directly, localStorage and sessionStorage do not retain the data set during the initial load at the root URL. This leads to issues in my application where user-specific data is missing or not loaded correctly.
I'm assuming that my issue has to do with the .htaccess or the server configuration since it only happens in production.
My .htaccess configuration in production:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect all requests to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

# Disable caching for index.html
<FilesMatch "index.html">
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
    Header set Expires "Mon, 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

What I've tried

Ensuring that the .htaccess redirects all requests to index.html as
recommended for Angular routing.
Verifying that localStorage and
sessionStorage are correctly set in the browser's console when
accessing the root URL. As stated above, when inspecting through Google Chrome dev tools, accesing from one URL will show the JWT stored in the local storage and the other one not.
Disabling caching for index.html to avoid any
stale data issues.

What I need
After all this information,

Is there something wrong with my .htaccess configuration that could be causing this issue?
Are there any additional settings I need to apply in Angular to ensure that localStorage and sessionStorage work correctly across all routes?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Access to localStorage/sessionStorage is only tied to the origin (protocol plus hostname plus port), and it appears that stays exactly the same here. Any internal rewriting you do on the server side, should not matter - only the URL on the client side decides, whether you are within the origin, or outside of it.

@C3roe how is It posible then that when inspecting the local storage in Google Chrome with the dev tools, the URL with no parameters shows an item in the local storage, and the other one doesn't?

Not really sure, tbh. Is this happening in other browsers as well, or just Chrome? I'd maybe try and remove those anti-caching headers, to see if those have any influence on this.

Found the real issue I've asked in this new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78950426/htacess-unable-to-remove-www-from-specific-urls
