.htacess unable to remove www from specific URLs
I have the following .htacess file:
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Remove 'www' from the URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect requests to index.html if the request is not for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]

My goal is the follwing:

https://www.example.com/a/anID should be redirected to
https://example.com/index.html
https://example.com/a/anID should be redirected to
https://example.com/index.html
https://www.example.com/index.html should be redirected to
https://example.com/index.html
https://example.com/index.html should be kept as
https://example.com/index.html

These is because I have an Angular application that will handle these scenarios if the URL doesn't point to an existing file or directory.
I've tried multiple variations of my .htaccess through this website and I'm unable to achieve these four rules.
Thanks in advance!

Your firs redirect rule is doing reverse i.e. adding a www. instead of removing it.

@anubhava you are right, I posted one of my first attemps, fixed it, thanks!

Ok with these updated rules, which URL is not working as you expected?

@anubhava basically if my URL has www in it, it will perform the first rule which is to remove the www from the URL. In this scenario, it won't continue since this will cause a redirect and the second part of the change of /index.html won't be done.

The final solution is:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove www and redirect to the non-www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://YourBaseHost/$1 [R=301,L]

# Ensure this block is processed only if not already redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]

Being your "YourBaseHost" the base host you want to redirect to.
With this it will work OK.
My issue was that "%1" was not getting properly the base host.
